# How to send an image as attachement from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email, email-attachments

1. I'm trying to send an email using a image type from mysql, as attachement.
   It keeps giving me an error 
   Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /srv/disk18/3303837/www/pommecannelle.lu/encomendas/php/sendmail.php on line 41

   Envio emailto


       
   --------------------------------------- 
       
       data:

   ```
   </form>
   <?php
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
       $sel=$_POST["Date"];

       require_once 'dbConfig.php'; 
       // Check connection
       if (!$mysqli) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
       }

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM Encomendas WHERE data='".$sel."'";

       $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

       if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


               $msg ='<html><body>';
               $msg .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">';
               $msg .= "Peso: " .$row["peso"]. "<br>"; 
               $msg .= "Massa: " .$row["massa"]. "<br>";
               $msg .= "Recheio: " .$row["recheio"] ."<br>";
               $msg .= "Cobertura: " .$row["cobertura"] ."<br>";
               $msg .= "Obs: " .$row["message"] ."<br>";
               $msg .= '</p></body></html>';

               $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
               $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
               $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'. "\r\n"; 
               $headers .= 'From: pomme <xxx@pomme.lu>' . "\r\n";   

               $headers .= '\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed;';

               ob_start();
               $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($row['imagem'])));

               if(mail("xxx@xxx.lu","Encomenda Pomme Cannelle",$msg,$headers)){
                   echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
               } else{
                   echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
               }   


           }
        } else {
          echo "0 results";
        }

        mysqli_close($mysqli);
       }
    ?>
   ```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps `print_r($row)` to see if the file path is valid and exists

Comment: You are open to injection. The width of the opening is moot (both in the sense of being debatable, and in the sense of having no practical relevance)

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: **file_get_contents**(): **Filename cannot be empty** in /srv/disk18/3303837/www/pommecannelle.lu/encomendas/php/sendmail.php on **line 41**

The value returned by `$row['imagem']` is empty. Check your database that the column exists and isn't empty for **any** rows. The first row with a null or empty **imagem** is causing this error.

You should check (a) if that row has a filename and (b) that the file was read successfully:

```php
ob_start();

$attachment = false;
if (!empty($row['imagem']) {
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($row['imagem']);

    if ($fileContents !== FALSE) {
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($fileContents));
    }
}

if ($attachment) {
    // Now send your email
    ...
}
```

I also noticed you never did anything with $attachment.

Depending on if this is a hobby vs. large-scale project, you should also check if the column exists with [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), and/or work on error handling as well.

P.S. - If this is anything important, please, please take a minute to learn about [SQL Injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20injection)